# Get theme URL without printing result

Tags: custom-post-types

I have this code to create a custom post type, but when I display an icon for this post type, it prints the theme URL:

```
'menu_icon' => ''.bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images/home-20.png',
```

I need the theme URL without printing it in `wp-admin`.

```
function units() {
    register_post_type( 'units',
        array( 
            'labels' => array (
                'name' => 'الوحدات',
                'singular_name' => 'الوحدات',
                'add_new' => 'اضافة جديد',
                'add_new_item' => 'اضافة جديد',
                'edit' => 'تعديل',
                'edit_item' => 'تعديل',
                'new_item' => 'اضافة جديد',
            ),
            '_builtin' => false,
            'public' => true, 
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5 ,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'page',
            'menu_icon' => ''.bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images/home-20.png',
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'units',
                'with_front' => false,
                'pages' => true
            ),
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'thumbnail',
                'editor',
            )
        ) 
    );
}
add_action('init', 'units');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to the codex on this issue of [`bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)

> This always prints a result to the browser. If you need the values for use in PHP, use [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo).

You should actually also not use either of the two, you should be using [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)